# Add JS Script to this HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add this "TimeCircles JavaScript but, I can't do it correctly, I will add the files of it in the following location: /js/count-down/timecircles.css and /js/count-down/timecircles.js

The HTML file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/diho8tcumte5pqr/coming-soon.html

The JS link: http://git.wimbarelds.nl/TimeCircles/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src='/js/count-down/timecircles.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<link href='/js/count-down/timecircles.css' type='text/css'/>
```

Stick this in the `head` of your HTML.

Comment: This? --> </br>$("#DateCountdown").TimeCircles({
    "animation": "smooth",
    "bg_width": 1.2,
    "fg_width": 0.1,
    "circle_bg_color": "#60686F",
    "time": {

        "Hours": {
            "text": "Hours",
            "color": "#99CCFF",
            "show": true
        },
        "Minutes": {
            "text": "Minutes",
            "color": "#BBFFBB",
            "show": true
        },
        "Seconds": {
            "text": "Seconds",
            "color": "#FF9999",
            "show": true
        }
    }
});

Comment: Place that code just before the closing `</body>` tag, and wrap the code with `<script>` tags.

Comment: Not Working, Here is the current HTML file: http://imagehosting.biz/images/2014/05/02/Capture.jpg

Comment: What do you mean 'not working'? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: The file is there in this place, and jquery is hosted at Google, What is that errors, May I try on a free web host for now?? http://imagehosting.biz/images/2014/05/02/Capture1.jpg

Comment: I will try to program the page from sctratch, It may be a conflict or something, Thanks for help!!

Comment: TimeCircles automatically takes on the size of the element it is placed in. You however have not given your element any size, that could be the problem.